# WPF. TextBox focuses after losing focus

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, onfocus, lost-focus

## Steps

- Subscribe TextBox focus events

```
_associatedObject.GotKeyboardFocus += OnAssociatedObjectGotKeyboardFocus;
_associatedObject.LostKeyboardFocus += OnAssociatedObjectLostKeyboardFocus;

_associatedObject.GotFocus += (s,e) =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GotFocus");
};

_associatedObject.LostFocus += (s, e) =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("LostFocus");
};

_associatedObject.IsKeyboardFocusedChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("IsKeyboardFocusedChanged");
};

_associatedObject.IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged");
};
```

- Raise LostFocusEvent after LostKeyboardFocus

```
private void OnAssociatedObjectLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    _associatedObject.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(UIElement.LostFocusEvent));
    Keyboard.ClearFocus();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("LostKeyboardFocus");
}
```

- Open the program and click on the TextBox;
- After the element has focus, click on the desktop, or in any other application, to remove focus from the TextBox element;
- Return focus to your application again.

## Expectations

After focusing the window, nothing should be added to the debug window because the element has been **LostFocus**.

## Result

```
IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged
IsKeyboardFocusedChanged
GotKeyboardFocus
IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged
IsKeyboardFocusedChanged
LostFocus
LostKeyboardFocus
LostFocus
```

[image]